# Mobile navigation not static

Tags: html, css, responsive

I made a navbar with a mobile media query, but when I try to hover over the hamburger menu, the navbar isn't static and I cant click any links.

Can anyone help me to fix this, I've already been trying for 90 mins :/

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dxmbc5p6/

All code in Jsfiddle:

```
<body class="animated fadeIn">
    <div class="nav animated fadeInDown">
       <img src="hamburger.png" alt="" class="hamburger">
       <div class="logo">
          <h1>TITLE</h1>
       </div>
       <ul>
           <li>
               <a href="#">PAGE</a>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">DROPDOWN</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">DROPDOWN</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">PAGE</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">PAGE</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">PAGE</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.nav .hamburger {
    display: none;
}

.nav .logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 150px;
}

.nav .logo h1 {
    color: #222;
    line-height: 10vh;
    font-size: 32px;
}

.nav > ul {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto !important;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 150px;
}

.nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}

.nav > ul > li:first-child > a:after {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: calc(5vh - 5px);
    margin-left: 8px;
    content: "";
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    margin-left: -50%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.nav ul a {
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 10vh;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: #999;
}

.landing {
    padding-top: 10vh;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('bg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px){
    .nav .hamburger {
        height: 6%;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 2% 0 0 2%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        position: fixed;
    }

    .nav .logo {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
        float: none;
    }

    .nav > ul {
        display: none;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .nav .hamburger:hover ~ ul {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

   .nav > ul:hover {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .nav ul:hover li {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .nav > ul > li {
        display: block;
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
    }

    .nav > ul > li > ul > li {
        background-color: #D4D4D4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the css.

`ul > li a,
    .nav > ul > li > ul > li a
    {
      display:block;
    }`

I will also point out that with a media tag detecting width as your way of detecting mobile. Your mobile site will display on desktops as well when the browser is shrunk below 850px. This will be a problem with your hover event as it will not fire after to mouse leaves the hamburger.

Comment: By the navbar not being static to you mean that the menu goes away when you are no longer hovering over the button?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because of the fact that as soon as you leave the image it looses it's hover state. Look at this example from your code:

```
<li>
  <li><a href="#">PAGE</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">DROPDOWN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DROPDOWN</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

And the CSS

```
.nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

You put the css on the first li which contains the section as well as the sub section. This way it doesn't matter if you are over the anchor element or the unordered list, they are still part of the first li so it is hovered.

**In the hamburger situation you put the hover css on a element which doesn't contain the menu** so as soon as you leave the hamburger image it looses it's hover state.